# Rspec/Capybara expects example.com but gets localhost. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: rspec, capybara

This is the output of my spec

expected: "http://www.example.com:3000/admin/biblebooks/1"
got: "http://127.0.0.1:61574/admin/biblebooks/1"

I already tried all sorts of things, like setting the apphost.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here's my spec:

```
feature "Admins can create new bible books" do
  before do
    login_as(create(:user, :admin))
    visit admin_biblebooks_path
    click_link t(:new_biblebook)
  end

  scenario "for single bible books" do
    bookname = "Handelingen"
    fill_in t("simple_form.labels.biblebook.name"), with: bookname
    fill_in t("simple_form.labels.biblebook.booksequence"), with: 0
    fill_in t("simple_form.labels.biblebook.testament"), with: "nieuw"

    submit_form

    should_see t(:item_created, item: Biblebook.model_name.human)
    book = Biblebook.find_by(name: "Handelingen")
    expect(page.current_url).to eq admin_biblebook_url(book)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default url options aren't configured to match in the test environment (`Rails.application.default_url_options`). You could configure that, but then you'd also have to deal with the dynamic port Capybara runs your app on too (easiest workaround for that would be to set a fixed port, but that raises potential conflict issues).  The real question to ask is why you care what hostname is being used? You likely don't and it shouldn't actually matter. I'd argue in 98% of cases the path being used doesn't actually matter to the user either, and validating that is unnecessary (unless you're using "friendly" urls and validating they're working correctly).

If you do decide you need to validate the path you really shouldn't be doing it the way you are (using the `eq` matcher), but instead should use the matchers Capybara provides, which in this case would be the `have_current_path` matcher.

```
expect(page).to have_current_path("/admin/biblebooks/#{book.id}")
```

Technically you could do

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_biblebook_path(book))
```

but then you're really just testing the path helper, not what you're actually expecting the user to see, so what's the point in testing it in the first place.